# DevExpress DisplayFormat in RowCellStyle

Tags: winforms, devexpress, decimal, xtragrid, displayformat

[image]Switching application to use DevExpress XtraGrid and implemented customized color and format for row/cells.

For most part formats are being applied correctly. However when applied to a decimal 1000 following format "#,###;(#,###);0" ends up 1000.0000 instead of 1,000.

```
gridView.RowCellStyle += CellFormatting;
private void CellFormatting(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)    
 {
        if (gridView.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle))
        {
            e.Appearance.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            e.Appearance.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            return;
        }

        // get cell by its index
        var gridRow = gridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        TLColumn columnEnum = ((BindableTextBoxColumn)e.Column).ColumnEnum;
        // get new format values 
        T row = (T)gridRow;

        e.Column.DisplayFormat.FormatString = row.GetCellFormat(columnEnum);
        e.Appearance.BackColor = row.GetCellBackColor(columnEnum);
        e.Appearance.ForeColor = row.GetCellColor(columnEnum);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bound columns that do not use CustomColumnDisplayText need to set FormatType before setting DisplayFormatString.

```
e.Column.ColumnType
```

can show type of the bound property

```
 private void CellFormatting(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
 {
       // get cell by its index
        var gridRow = gridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        var column = (BindableTextBoxColumn)e.Column;
        TLColumn columnEnum = column.ColumnEnum;
        // get new format values 
        T row = (T)gridRow;

        e.Column.DisplayFormat.FormatType = (column.IsNumeric) ? FormatType.Numeric : column.DisplayFormat.FormatType;
        e.Column.DisplayFormat.FormatString = row.GetCellFormat(columnEnum);
        if (gridView.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle))
        {
            e.Appearance.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            e.Appearance.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            return;
        }
        e.Appearance.BackColor = row.GetCellBackColor(columnEnum);
        e.Appearance.ForeColor = row.GetCellColor(columnEnum);
}
```